# How to change the name of the topic generated by Kafka Connect Source Connector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, mongodb-kafka-connector

I have an already running production deployed Kafka-Cluster and having Topic "*existing-topic*". I am using MongoDB-Source-Connector from Debezium.

Here all what I want is to push the CDC events directly to the topic "*existing-topic*" so that my consumers which are already listening to that topic will process it.

I didn't find any resource to do it so, however it's mentioned that topic is created in below format -

"If your mongodb.name parameter is A, database name is B and collection name is C, the data from database A and collection C will be loaded under the topic A.B.C"

Can I change the topic to "existing-topic" and push the events to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/mongodb.html#mongodb-topic-names),

> The name of the Kafka topics **always** takes the form
>   `logicalName.databaseName.collectionName`, where `logicalName` is the
>   [logical name](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.1/connectors/mongodb.html#logical-connector-name) of the connector as specified with the `mongodb.name`
>   configuration property, `databaseName` is the name of the database where
>   the operation occurred, and `collectionName` is the name of the MongoDB
>   collection in which the affected document existed.

---

This means that if your connector's logical name is `myConnector` and your database `myDatabase` has two collections `users` and `orders`

```
{
  "name": "myConnector",  
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mongodb.MongoDbConnector", 
    "mongodb.hosts": "mongo-db-host:27017", 
    "mongodb.name": "myDatabase", 
    "collection.whitelist": "myDatabase[.]*", 
  }
}
```

then Kafka Connect will populate two topics with names:

- `myConnector.myDatabase.users`
- `myConnector.myDatabase.orders`

---

Now if you still want to change the name of the target topic, you can make use of Kafka Connect Single Message Transforms (SMT). More precisely, [`ExtractTopic`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/extracttopic.html#extracttopic) should help you. Note though that this SMT helps you extract the topic name from the key or value of the message, therefore you somehow need to include the desired topic name in the payload.

For example, the following SMT will extract the value of field `myField` and use this as the record's topic:

```
 transforms.ValueFieldExample.type=io.confluent.connect.transforms.ExtractTopic$Value
 transforms.ValueFieldExample.field=myField
```

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same problem with the JDBC Source Connector and found a different solution:

Using the [`RegexRouter`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/regexrouter.html#regexrouter) Single Message Transform with `dropPrefix` you can just override the whole topic name:

```
"transforms":"dropPrefix",
"transforms.dropPrefix.regex":"A.B.C",                 // whole created topic name
"transforms.dropPrefix.replacement":"existing-topic"   // whole exisiting topic name
```

And it works with regex, so if you're using multiple tables/collections and your created topic name isn't constant, you should be able to make it dynamic.

It's a bit hacky as technically I'm dropping the whole topic name and then adding a new topic name - which isn't the best solution, to me anyway.

Comment: if i am using this transforms in JDBC sink connector and i am using this transforms, what value should i give to parameter "table.name.format" if i want output of this transforms as my destination table name

Comment: Haven't tried transforms yet and I need apply that in mongo source connector. Will check how it can fit in it.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and i found this asnwer.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/kafka-connector/current/source-connector/usage-examples/topic-naming/#database-and-collection-names

Here we can add a mapping to connector config, a property called `topic.namespace.map`. Using that we can map mongo `database.collection` --> `exsiting_topic`.
For example,

If i have a collection called `eventstore` in `test` mongo database and i want to publish it to `different_topic` in Kafka. `topic.namespace.map` property would look like this.

`{topic.namespace.map: {"test.eventstore": "different_topic"}}`